# Different webpage alert for different browser?

Tags: javascript, html

i am making a website in asp.net which works fine in chrome and firefox but it is not good enough in IE, so i want a code to display a message for IE that it is not supported in IE. However i tried this code i.e,

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]> 
<script type="text/javascript">  
     alert('Your version of Internet Explorer doesn\'t support.')
</script>
 <![endif]-->
```

but unfortunately it displays in chrome also ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use just IE in your condition like nelow, then it will work.

```
<!--[if IE]><!-->
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert("Please use another browser");
</script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [**navigator.userAgent**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent) api to get the browser information.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     // for ie < 11
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if(/MSIE \d/.test(navigator.userAgent))
            alert("Will only work in IE below IE11")
    </script>
</head>
<body>
```

for above 10

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
         // for ie < 11
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if(/Trident.*rv:/.test(navigator.userAgent))
                alert("Will work for IE11")
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
```

On running `navigator.userAgent` in ie browser console you may see this which may vary a little depending on ie version

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

`Trident.*rv` is taken from output of the api

Comment: Thanks, this works great ! can you please tell the code for alert which will works in firefox only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax, for **if IE**:

```
    <!--[if IE]>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           alert("Please use another browser");
        </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

If **not IE**:

```
        <!--[if !IE]><!-->
              <script type="text/javascript">
                   alert("Please use another browser");
                </script>
        <!--<![endif]-->
```